# execl not capturing all arguments

Tags: c, exec

What could possibly be wrong with this `execl` statement? When I try to run it, the receiving executable complains that the `argc` is less than 3. When I print the argv contents, I get the following:

```
argv[1] = -1076146944
argv[2] = 0
```

Despite the arguments consisting of:

```
numJoeysStr = 6
randomNumSeedStr = 7

execl("/path/to/executable", "numJoeysStr", "randNumSeedStr", (char *)0);
```

FWIW, I tried NULL in replace of (char *)0). That didn't make a difference.

Chris Jester-Young resolved my biggest issue, but now I get the following after placing in the function twice:

```
argv[1] = -1075725068
argv[2] = -1075725056
```

I tried dereferencing, by doing:

```
printf("argv[1] = %d\n", *argv[1]);
printf("argv[2] = %d\n", *argv[2]);
```

Only to receive the following:

```
argv[1] = 110
argv[2] = 114
```

When I expected:

```
argv[1] = 6
argv[2] = 7
```

For the final problem, it turns out that passing the variables into `execl` without the quotes gave it the numbers I expected. I was somehow under the impression that all `execl` arguments (aside from the last) must be in quotes, even the variables.

Comment: Why do you print the arguments as integers instead of as strings?

Comment: Oh right! Let me try strtol()

Comment: I commented that before your edit. Your new problem is that you're printing the ASCII value of the first character, which is not what you want. (And yes, `strtol` will convert the decimal form of a number (in a string) to the actual number)

Comment: @immibis - see the final edit

Comment: @user1185790 You should use `%s` for strings, not `%d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually need to specify `"/path/to/executable"` *twice*. The first one is the program to execute, and the second one is the `argv[0]` for the new process.

Comment: Great, thank you! I now have argv[1] = -1076376332, and argv[2] = -1076376320. I'm assuming these arguments are pointers that must be dereferenced.

Comment: Good answer.  Actually, you don't need to put the program name twice, but you have to put something that will be passed to the program as argv[0].  You can change argv[0], even to lie to the program being executed.  Convention mandates to put the program name but it's only a convention.

Comment: @LuisColorado Yes, you can pass anything you want to `argv[0]` (it can even be null on some operating systems, which would mean that the new process will have `argc == 0`), but by convention, you should pass the program name by default, because that's what the shell does.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, in linux, that's a way (passing no arguments) to let a `.so` library to reveal which modules it needs (it's used by **ldd(1)** program)